# php pdo mssql declare insert select

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, sqlsrv

I'm trying access to a MS SQL server using PHP PDO:SQLSRV or PHP SQLSRV.

For PHP PDO:SQLSRV, I'm using this code:

```
<?php

    try {
        $db = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=sql_server;Database=database", "username", "password");
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $test = $db->prepare('declare @t2 code.instancereferencestable;
                              insert into @t2 select top 10 [Instance Reference] from imported.instance where [Instance Type] = \'CENAS\' and [Instance Reference] = \'CENAS.8000\' order by [Instance (Id)] desc;
                              select * from transformed.attribute_instance_extended_from_references(@t2)');
        $test->execute();
        $test->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        echo "Connected!". "\n";
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    }

?>
```

For PHP SQLSRV, I'm using this code:

```
<?php

    $serverName = "sql_server";
    $connectionOptions = array(
        "Database" => "database",
        "Uid" => "username",
        "PWD" => "password"
    );

    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);
    if ( $conn ) {
        echo "Connection established.".PHP_EOL;

        $sql = ("declare @t2 code.instancereferencestable;
                insert into @t2 select top 10 [Instance Reference] from imported.instance where [Instance Type] = 'CENAS' and [Instance Reference] = 'CENAS.8000' order by [Instance (Id)] desc;
                select * from transformed.attribute_instance_extended_from_references(@t2);");

        $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
        if ( $stmt === false ) {
               die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        } else {
            $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt); 
            print_r ($row);
        }

    } else {
            echo "Connection could not be established.".PHP_EOL;
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)).PHP_EOL;
    }

?>
```

The output that I get from the PHP PDO:SQLSRV is:
Error: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: The active result for the query contains no fields.

And from the PHP SQLSRV I have no output.

I run the same SQL code directly in the SQL Server Management Studio and I have output.

Can anyone help!?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot run multiple statements in one PDO query. Break it apart into multiple queries.

Comment: Don't you need to navigate with `PDOStatement::nextRowset()` / `sqlsrv_next_result()` until the appropriate result set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution could be creating a Stored Procedure and call that instead.

Also you could try using php_mssql.dll module.
Info here: http://php.net/manual/es/book.mssql.php

Comment: tomcontr, thanks for the tip.
creating a Stored Procedure works.

Comment: No problem, remember to mark the answer as answered.